Implementing Initial Conditions in Autonomous Differential Equation
I have the differential equation $ yy'' - 5(y')^2 + y^2 = 0$ with initial conditions $y(0) = 1$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}(0) = 0$ and have been asked to use reduction of order to solve it.
With the substitution $v = y'$ and $v' = v \frac{dv}{dy}$, we get the Bernoulli differential equation:
$$\frac{dv}{dy} = \frac{5v}{y} - \frac{y}{v}$$
After making the substitution $u(y) = v^2$ and using variation of parameters, I get $\frac{dy}{dx} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{4} + C_1y^{10}}$. I have verified that this solves the original equation.
I don't see how I can implement the initial condition with the derivative at x = 0 as the ODE is autonomous in x. I see, however, that integrating the last equation gives a relationship between $C_1$ and the new integration constant (say $C_2$) when $y(0)=1$ is used.

If you substitute $x = 0$ into your given 1st order DE, then you use both of the initial conditions to solve for $C_1$ - on the right side you'll use $y(0) = 1$, and on the left side you'll use $\frac{dy}{dx}(0) = 0$ to get
$$0 = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1^2}{4} + C_1 (1^{10})}$$

How would we interpret the +- solutions? This seems to imply 2 solutions for each of the integration constants, whereas a total of 2 solutions would be expected from the equation being 2nd order.

You can solve both branches of the DE, and you'll find that one of them works for positive $x$ and the other for negative $x$, and you can stitch them together (in fact it's a little simpler than that because they wind up being the same function coming from two different directions anyway). That only happens under these specific initial conditions though, with different conditions the choice of $\pm$ would actually be forced.
